# UEFI UDP4 - handling multiple interfaces

Tags: network-programming, udp, uefi

I've explored a lot of different examples of UDP code for UEFI, but for the most part they fall back to "assume we have only one network interface" and use `LocateProtocol` rather than `LocateHandleBuffer`. The system where I'm testing this appears to have 3 interfaces (although I can't figure out what these would be - I'm assuming maybe one is loopback). So this raises a couple of questions:

1. I presume that I need to do `OpenProtocol()` on each of the multiple handles, followed by `CreateChild()` to get from "service binding protocol" to "protocol" and then an `OpenProtocol()` on the latter?
2. At what point can I get useful information to distinguish the interfaces and choose one, and possibly terminate the loop early?
3. Do I use `Configure()` on each child handle, or have I somehow filtered out the wrong ones before this?
4. There's a note in the UEFI Spec that `OpenProtocol()` should be used in place of `HandleProtocol()` in new code, but very few examples show this and it seems awkward since the same spec suggests the latter is just a wrapper around the former with fixed arguments. Is there really a good reason to prefer `OpenProtocol()`?

If anyone can explain this in terms of a standard POSIX socket model, that might make it more comprehensible to someone who's not used to all these weird layers of indirection in UEFI.

Comment: #4. OpenProtocol tracks the open protocol, both so that it can be closed when the caller is unloaded and so that the producer of the protocol cannot be unloaded while the protocol is still open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1) You can call gBS->LocateHandleBuffer to get all EFI_UDP4_SERVICE_BINDING_PROTOCOL instances, then you call CreateChild on each of them. On every handle you use OpenProtocol.

Q2&Q3) For each child you can call GetModeData, set Udp4ConfigData to NULL so you don't need to call configure on each instance.
With the SnpModeData parameter for GetModeData you get informations about the interface (mac address, type, ...). Do not forget to call DestroyChild for each child you do not want to use.

Q4) Many of the attributes for OpenProtocol are meant to be used by other drivers. In an application you can use BY_HANDLE_PROTOCOL (or use HandleProtocol instead), TEST_PROTOCOL and EXCLUSIVE. Why you should use OpenProtocol [was already meantioned by prl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70352441/uefi-udp4-handling-multiple-interfaces#comment124369509_70352441).